# How to create recursive function to find out hierarchical order in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following table with a list of employees, its name, and the employee that is in charge of them. (ex. IDEmployee 1001 reports to IDEmployee 1000)

```
IDEmployee  Name ReportsTo
1000        A    Null
1001        B    1000
1002        c    1001
1003        d    1001
2000        e    null
1004        f    1002
2001        g    2000
2003        h    2000
2004        i    2003
2005        j    2000
1004        k    1003
2006        l    1003
1007        m    2005
2008        n    null
1110        o    2008
2100        p    1110
```

The hierarchy level is the value in the hierarchy that the employee has. When the value is "null", it means it has the highest hierarchy level, since no other employeeID is above him, assigning it a level 1.

And the expected result is that a table "tblHierarchy" is created with the following values:

```
IdEmployee  HierarchyLevel
1000        1
1001        2
1002        3
1004        4
1003        2
2006        3
1005        3
2000        1
2001        2
2003        2
2004        3
2005        2
1007        3
2008        1
1100        2
2100        3
```

How can I implement a function in MySQL that can be executed and updates the tblHierarchy with the latests hierarchy values?

Comment: In MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive CTE; in earlier versions, you'll need to use a stored procedure or client side code.